# Outlook 2010 keeps asking for password

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook-2010

Every time I open Outlook it prompts me for the password. I enter it, click Remember, and it seems to stick for that session... until I close Outlook and re-open it later, it prompts me again and acts like it totally forgot.

When I go into Outlook account settings and make sure "Prompt for credentials" in unchecked, doesn't matter. It always, always, always asks for credentials.

How do I get this thing to remember the password?

Comment: First we need to know what sort of account you're using Outlook to read.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that Protected Storage System Provider doesn't work properly. Try to open Registry Editor and navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Protected Storage System Provider`, then delete a subkey named with *S-1-5-21*. If the deletion operation is blocked, you may need to [take ownership of that registry key](https://www.maketecheasier.com/full-ownership-windows-registry-keys/) first.

If the above method doesn't work, try to [create a new Outlook profile](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-an-outlook-profile-f544c1ba-3352-4b3b-be0b-8d42a540459d) and set up your email account. Hope the issue will gone.

Answer (score 0):

This issue could be related to many sides.

Please refer to the thread below and see if it will be helpful.

[Why does Outlook keep prompting for password](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bcd2d9c2-1a1b-4446-bf32-69fee8cdf11b/why-does-outlook-keep-prompting-for-password?forum=outlook)